# Create a div containing a form appear within another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried several variations of this code and can't get anything to work. I'm trying to make a div containing a form appear within another div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttoncontact").click(function(){
          $("#back").append('<div id="#contact">
             <form>
             Email:<br>
             <input type="text"><br>
             Comments:<br>
             <textarea rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
             </form>
             </div>');
      });
});
```

I've also tried to just insert the div without the form code inside it and that won't work either.

Any help you could offer would be great.

Comment: Javascript doesn't allow you to continue strings across multiple lines. Aren't you getting syntax errors in the Javascript console? Did you even look there before posting?

Comment: Quick thing to do yourself. Check the console for any errors..

Comment: Why you don't include the form in the html template and hide it at default? The only thing you have to do is to make it visible, for example: $("#buttoncontact").click(function(){$('#contact').show(); }); This method is easier to maintain and there is no html in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't allow to go to new line inside a variable or a string n your way.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#buttoncontact").click(function(){
            $("#back").append('<div id="#contact"><form>Email:<br><input type="text"><br>Comments:<br><textarea rows="8" cols="50"></textarea></form></div>');
        });
});
```

Comment: if the answer has solved the problem accept it to help other guys with your sampe problem @user2779956

Answer (score 0):

## [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J7k37/)

JavaScript doesn't let you to break your strings into multiple lines. You can write the whole string contet into one line, or if you want to make it readable then concatenate them with the `+` operator.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#buttoncontact").click(function(){
      $("#back").append(
         '<div id="#contact">' +
            '<form>' +
               'Email:<br>' +
               '<input type="text"><br>' +
               'Comments:<br>' +
               '<textarea rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>' +
            '</form>' +
         '</div>'
      );
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support [multi-line strings](http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings) like that; semi-colons are automatically added at the end of lines. So, spreading the appended HTML string across multiple lines is probably creating a syntax errors for the code.

You can either condense the HTML string to a single line, or build multi-line strings by concatenating multiple strings with the plus-sign (+) :

```
$("#back").append('<div id="contact">' +
'<form>' +
'Email:<br>' +
'</form>' +
'</div>');
```

Or, adding a backslash (\) to the end of each line:

```
$("#back").append('<div id="contact">\
<form>\
Email:<br>\
</form>\
</div>');
```